# My Arabic language is showing all numbers first and then Arabic words are coming in Ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am working in my Ionic 4 app and I have added multilingual in my app. In English, the text is coming properly but in the Arabic, Numbers are coming first and then Arabic words are coming.

This is my **tab2.page.html**:

```
<p class="myp11">
    {{ challengesuser.target }} {{ 'STEPS_IN' | translate }} <span>{{ challengesuser.duration }}</span>
</p>
```

In this, I am showing the value coming from the server and Some parameters which is translated according to the language selected.

But the problem is that, in Arabic, numbers are coming first:

[image]

In English, it is coming correct like this :

> 7000 steps in 30 days

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: have you set lang and dir?

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari. I have set lang and it is working fine, but the only this problem is coming and I have not set any dir.

Comment: dir is most important for rtl/ltr direction

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari. Okay can you tell me how to set that and for this only, Can you please suggest some other method?